# How to randomly subset X% of selected points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, editing, arcgis-10.2, random

What methods are available in ArcGIS 10.2 to randomly subset a selection of points.  For example, in the attached screenshot I am interested in keeping 20% of the selected points and deleting the rest.

[image]

Comment: Well I don't think there is a default method for selecting random points from layer. Did you try with python script? Or add-in?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a python function that will select random features in a layer based on percent, ignoring current selection:

```py
def SelectRandomByPercent (layer, percent):
    #layer variable is the layer name in TOC
    #percent is percent as whole number  (0-100)
    if percent > 100:
        print "percent is greater than 100"
        return
    if percent < 0:
        print "percent is less than zero"
        return
    import random
    fc = arcpy.Describe (layer).catalogPath
    featureCount = float (arcpy.GetCount_management (fc).getOutput (0))
    count = int (featureCount * float (percent) / float (100))
    if not count:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        return
    oids = [oid for oid, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, "OID@")]
    oidFldName = arcpy.Describe (layer).OIDFieldName
    path = arcpy.Describe (layer).path
    delimOidFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (path, oidFldName)
    randOids = random.sample (oids, count)
    oidsStr = ", ".join (map (str, randOids))
    sql = "{0} IN ({1})".format (delimOidFld, oidsStr)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "", sql)
```

Copy/paste this into the python shell in ArcMap.

Then in the shell type `SelectRandomByPercent ("layer", num)`, where `layer` is the name of your layer, and `num` is a whole number of your percent.

[image: Random selection]

A variation to find a subset selection as asked:

```py
def SelectRandomByPercent (layer, percent):
    #layer variable is the layer name in TOC
    #percent is percent as whole number  (0-100)
    if percent > 100:
        print "percent is greater than 100"
        return
    if percent < 0:
        print "percent is less than zero"
        return
    import random
    featureCount = float (arcpy.GetCount_management (layer).getOutput (0))
    count = int (featureCount * float (percent) / float (100))
    if not count:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        return
    oids = [oid for oid, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (layer, "OID@")]
    oidFldName = arcpy.Describe (layer).OIDFieldName
    path = arcpy.Describe (layer).path
    delimOidFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (path, oidFldName)
    randOids = random.sample (oids, count)
    oidsStr = ", ".join (map (str, randOids))
    sql = "{0} IN ({1})".format (delimOidFld, oidsStr)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "", sql)
```

Finally, one more variation to select a layer by a count, instead of a percent:

```py
def SelectRandomByCount (layer, count):
    import random
    layerCount = int (arcpy.GetCount_management (layer).getOutput (0))
    if layerCount < count:
        print "input count is greater than layer count"
        return
    oids = [oid for oid, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (layer, "OID@")]
    oidFldName = arcpy.Describe (layer).OIDFieldName
    path = arcpy.Describe (layer).path
    delimOidFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (path, oidFldName)
    randOids = random.sample (oids, count)
    oidsStr = ", ".join (map (str, randOids))
    sql = "{0} IN ({1})".format (delimOidFld, oidsStr)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "", sql)
```

Comment: Nice use of `random.sample()`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I updated the answer for a subset selection without exporting first.

Comment: +1. Are there any known limitations on string length for the `sql` parameter?

Comment: @Paul I just tested this code to select 100% of features with a layer that has nearly 4 million features, which resulted in a memory error. So while there doesn't appear to be a hard string limit, there is a dependency on memory. There is also an SQL item limit for Oracle SDE databases, which I've blogged about here: http://emilsarcpython.blogspot.com/2015/10/working-around-oracles-sql-where-clause.html

Comment: just used this. works great!

Comment: Esri used this code in a blog https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013141

Answer (score 14):

Generally, I also recommend using the spatial ecology tools as discussed by blah238.

However, another method you could try would be to add an attribute called Random to store a random number: 
[image]

Then, using the field calculator on that attribute, with the Python Parser, use the following codeblock:

```
import random
def rand():
  return random.random()
```

See image below:

This will create random values between 0 and 1.  Then, if you want to select 20% of the features, you could select features where the Random value is less than 0.2.  Of course, this will work better with many features.  I created a feature class with only 7 features as a test and there were no values less than 0.2.  However, it looks like you have plenty of features, so that shouldn't matter.

[image]

Comment: this method will return *on average* 20% of the features, which in some cases would be preferred. But if you want 20% every time, you can do as suggested, then sort the features by the random value and select the first 20%.

Comment: Esri used this process in a blog: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013141

Answer (score 6):

There is also an earlier [Select features at random](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15441) script from @StephenLead available for ArcGIS Desktop.  Although written, I think, for ArcGIS 9.x, and last modified in 2008, I used it in about 2010 at 10.0, and it still worked well.

Answer (score 5):

You could try Hawth's Tools: http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/rndsel.php

Note that the existing selection is not honored so you would have to make a feature layer from the existing selection first.

Comment: Unfortunately, that version isn't compatible with ArcGIS 9.3 and above. Now it's called Geospatial Modelling Environment: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme

Comment: Good point, here is the equivalent command in GME: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/rsample.htm

Comment: The GME toolset does not work "within" ArcGIS, rather it is a stand alone tool

Answer (score 3):

Here's another random selection add-in for ArcGIS 10, the [Sampling Design Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbe1fc44f35465f9dea42ef9b63e785). It will let you select 20% of the features in your dataset. However, this doesn't use a selected set to make a random selection, similar to the restrictions of the Hawth's Tools mentioned by blah238.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Subset Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/latest/tools/geostatistical-analyst-toolbox/subset-features.htm) tool. According to the documentation:

> Divides the original dataset into two parts: one part to be used to
>   model the spatial structure and produce a surface, the other to be
>   used to compare and validate the output surface.

One disadvantage is that you need the Geostatistical Analyst extension.