# Preparing data for semiovariogram analysis in ArcGIS with large sample sizes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, geostatistical-analyst

I am working on a statewide project to create surface water quality grids from point samples.  In some instances, we have large sample sizes (n>50,000) which is problematic when creating semiovariograms in ArcGIS' Geostatistical Analyst.  See my sample locations for groundwater pH.  I'm looking for some literature on how to sub-sample my data prior to interpolation so I can look at the semiovariogram, trends and geostatistics.

[image: pH_point_Samples]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your desire, there are many ways you can go about this. One example would be to use the [Subset Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geostatistical-analyst/subset-features.htm) tool. You can create a random subset based on your desired percentage of the original. If you want to be more python-y, the top answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78251/how-to-randomly-subset-x-of-selected-points) has a good example.
You can also check you the add-in tool here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbe1fc44f35465f9dea42ef9b63e785