# Random Selection using Select By Attributes tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, sql, select-by-attribute, random

How I can make a SQL syntax to generate "RANDOM SELECTION" in Select by attributes tool in ArcMap?.

E.g. We have two kind of sample: Quantitative an Qualitative data.

- Quantitative (seven cases):
  1,2,5,8,23,76,99,567,34,596,36,28,11
- Qualitative (four cases):
  "dogs","parrots","lions","cats","turtles","tigers","pigs" and "ducks".

My aim is generate a random selection in quantitative cases, just seven cases of the whole sample (e.g. 34,5, 28, 596 and 2). And qualitative cases, just four cases of the whole sample (e.g. "pigs", "cats","tigers" and "dogs").

How I can make it?

Is it the same to mix quantitative(Double Type) and qualitative (String Type) cases?

---

I don't know how to use arcgis.rand() and pythons random.

Can you teach me step by step thoguh Field Calculator or Select by attributes?

Like this picture...

I think this in vbscript[image]

The idea is to do random selections in COD_MOD variable (0515012, 4789512, 4563728, etc). In addition, I want to have a random selection with 1000 features as maximum.

Comment: You could use Field Calculator with [`arcgis.rand()`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/the-distribution-syntax-for-random-values.htm) or python's [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module. From there, your SQL query might be something like `"randField IN (1,2,3,4...)"`.

Comment: What is your data stored in?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78251/how-to-randomly-subset-x-of-selected-points